# Supposed to print number of upper and lowercase but returns 1 and exits program

Tags: c++, uppercase, lowercase

I had the program working until I wrote it with a void function. I have no idea where I've messed up. It returns 1 and gives no other errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
char response;
string s;
int upper, lower, other, count;
void capCheck(string);
int main()
{
    count = 0;
    upper = 0;
    lower = 0;
do
{
    cout<<"Get the number of upper and lower case letters in your sentence!!"<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Type your sentence below without spaces.."<<endl;
    cin>>s; 
    capCheck(s);    
    cout<<"Would you like to continue? Y/N"<<endl;
    cin>>response;
}while(response == 'y' || response == 'Y');
return 0;    
}
void capCheck()
{
    while(s[count] != 0)
    {
        if(s[count] >= 'a' && s[count] <= 'z')
        {
            lower++;
            count++;
        }
        else if (s[count] >= 'A' && s[count] <= 'Z')
        {
            upper++;
            count++;
        }
        else
            other++;
    }
    cout<<"The number of uppercase letters are: "<<upper<<endl;
    cout<<"The number of lowercase letters are: "<<lower<<endl; 
}
```

Comment: well that code does not even compile for me.

Comment: Your declaration and definition of `capCheck` don't match, and you should be learning to do this without using global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `void capCheck()` for `void capCheck(string s)` in your function declaration. It works fine for me.

Some comments on the code: try not to use global variables and improve indenation.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ for sure! I said that because he/shw commented my answer not yours :)

Comment: Lol sorry guys. It won't let me up vote because I'm not high enough reputation

Answer (score 1):

At your function definition put

```
void capCheck(string s) { 
    // ... 
}
```

See [live demo](http://ideone.com/a9do0D).

The provided function definition signature

```
void capCheck() { 
    // ... 
}
```

doesn't match the actual declaration of your function prototype's signature

```
void capCheck(string);
```

---

> "I have no idea where I've messed up. It returns 1 and gives no other errors."

The program doesn't compile in the form you've posted your code. Probably the build process stops prematurely (note there isn't any path in your `main()` function returning `1`).